# How to make width of the TOC horizontally resizable

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

The TOC (Table Of Contents) in the HTML rendered from my Asciidoctor documents is fixed, and I would like to be able to resize it in the horizontal. This would be very convenient to adjust the TOC when its entries ocupy more than two lines.

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the width for `#toc.toc2{width:20em}` in your CSS file.

Comment: Well, it does not let me resize dynamically the TOC inside the browser, but it does resize statically. Anyway, thanks a lot !